# Jquery check if next element input is a button

Tags: jquery, html, input

I am using this function to check for `Enter Key` presses and mimics the action of a `Tab Key` press. However, when the user reaches the last input:text i'd like it to accept the `Enter Key` and not use the function

Is this possible?

```
$('input').live("keypress", function (e) {
    /* ENTER PRESSED*/
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /* FOCUS ELEMENT */
        var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(":input");
        var idx = inputs.index(this);
        if (idx == inputs.length - 1) {
            inputs[0].select()
        } else {
            inputs[idx + 2].focus(); // Skips two inputs
            inputs[idx + 2].select();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: If your using a current version of jquery you shouldn't use live, instead use on()

Answer (score 2):

You should move the `return` statement into the `else` block:

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input', function (e) {
    /* ENTER PRESSED*/
    if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
        /* FOCUS ELEMENT */
        var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(":input");
        var idx = inputs.index(this);
        if (idx == inputs.length - 1) {
            inputs[0].select()
        } else {
            inputs[idx + 2].focus(); // Skips two inputs
            inputs[idx + 2].select();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

**P.S.** You should look into caching your selectors. Since I don't know your specific use case, I can't properly help you, but querying the DOM *on every keypress* is **a recipe for disaster**.

---

Without knowing exactly how you're using this, here's a quick example of caching:

```
var inputs;

$(document).on('keypress', 'input', function (e) {
    if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
        inputs = inputs || $(this).closest('form').find(":input");
        // The rest of your code...
    }
});
```

This checks if `inputs` already has a value, and if not, it queries the DOM.

Comment: What does caching the selectors involve?

Comment: @claw - For starters, storing `$(this).closest('form').find(":input")` into a variable outside of the `keypress` event handler. That way, you'll only ever query the DOM once.